# Problems using psycopg2 on Mac OS (Yosemite)

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, postgresql, psycopg2

Currently I am installing psycopg2 for work within eclipse with python.

I am finding a lot of problems:

1. The first problem `sudo pip3.4 install psycopg2` is not working and it is showing the following message

> Error: pg_config executable not found.

FIXED WITH:`export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/:"$PATH”`

2. When I import psycopg2 in my project i obtein:

> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
>   Library libssl.1.0.0.dylib
>   Library libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib

FIXED WITH: 
`sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib`

3. Now I am obtaining:

> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so,
>   2): Symbol not found: _lo_lseek64   Referenced from:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
>   Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib  in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so

Can you help me?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You need to replace the /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib library because its version is too old.
Here's my solution to this problem:

```
$ sudo mv /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib.old  
$ sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/lib
```

Comment: Thank you @KungFuLucky7 I will try it and i will say you

Comment: This worked for me after upgrading to Yosemite. If you're using the postgres app then the second command should be:

    sudo ln -s /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/lib

Comment: I'm seeing ln: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib: Operation not permitted

Comment: Great: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659348/operation-not-permitted-when-on-root-el-capitan-rootless-disabled. So I have to go into recovery mode, disable System Integrity Protection, and then relink the libraries.

Answer (score 28):

If you are using PostgresApp, you need to run the following two commands:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib.old
sudo ln -s /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/lib
```

Comment: This worked for me. But I am proceeding cautiously. The thing that I am unclear about, is how this could affect other apps on my system that are dependent on a previous version of PostgreSQL that is installed on my system (OSX Mavericks).

Comment: This works for me. I had a Postgresql installed before, and then I installed the PostgreSQL app, the same error occured when I uninstalled the previous installation. And this question solves my problem, not sure why, but kudos!

Answer (score 15):

I was able to fix this on my Mac (running Catalina, 10.15.3) by using psycopg2-binary rather than psycopg2.

`pip3 uninstall psycopg2
pip3 install psycopg2-binary`

Comment: Worked for me on Catalina as well

Answer (score 4):

I am using yosemite, postgres.app & django. this got psycopg2 to load properly for me but the one difference was that my `libpq.5.dylib` file is in `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/lib`.

thus my second line was `sudo ln -s  /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/lib`

Comment: Did you run the first line to move the old library?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fix that worked for me on El Capitan that doesn't require restarting to work around the OS X El Capitan System Integrity Protection (SIP):

```
brew unlink postgresql && brew link postgresql
brew link --overwrite postgresql
```

[H/T Farhan Ahmad](http://www.thebitguru.com/blog/view/432-psycopg2%20on%20El%20Capitan)

Comment: On my OS X Yosemite 10.10.3, I had to add -force and the --overwrite wasn't needed:    brew unlink postgresql94 && brew link -force postgresql94

Comment: Using the official Postgresql install .dmg caused some of these errors for me. Reinstalling using brew seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you on El Capitan who can't use @KungFuLucky7's answer - I used the following to fix the issue (Adjust paths to match yours where required).

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libpq.5.dylib /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
```

Answer (score 1):

In El Capitan, I used the same solution as @Forbze but 2 more commands as follows.

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libpq.5.dylib /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libpq.5.dylib  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
sudo install_name_tool -change libssl.1.0.0.dylib /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
sudo install_name_tool -change libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
```

It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

well, I'd like to give my solution, the problem is related with the version of c. So, I just typed:

```
CFLAGS='-std=c99' pip install psycopg2==2.6.1
```

Comment: On El Capitan, it helped when I used this version of psycopg2: `CFLAGS='-std=c99' pip install psycopg2==2.6`