# ImportError with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I've been trying to install **psycopg2** on my OS X Yosemite machine for the past two days. I have python, postgreSQL installed. I've tried installing psycopg2 using:

```
sudo pip install psycopg2
```

It gets successfully installed, but when I import it in the python shell, I get this:

```
import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", 
line 50, in <module> from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): 
Symbol not found: _lo_lseek64
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
in /Library/Frameworks/Python.frame
```

I've looked at all the Stack Overflow questions related to this. Nothing works!
I've also tried mac ports and I get a similar result.

update:
 I did what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515972/problems-using-psycopg2-on-mac-os-yosemite) said. Now I'm getting this:

`ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Reason: image not found`

Comment: Have you tried reverting to python 2.7 and install it again. I feel there might be some compatibility issue.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515972/problems-using-psycopg2-on-mac-os-yosemite

Comment: Cannot replicate. I have tried installing `psycopg2` (Version 2.6.1) in a virtualenv with Python 3.4.3 on OS X Yosemite. Importing  `psycopg2` works without problems. Can you tell which versions you're using? `pip freeze` should help to see what version of `psycopg2` you have installed on your system.

Comment: This doesn't work as well .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515972/problems-using-psycopg2-on-mac-os-yosemite

Comment: I have psycopg2 version 2.6.1 installed.